# Obtaining an analytical expression for a definite integral including an inverse square root

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to obtain an analytical form for the following definite integral, in which $f$ and $b$ are positive quantities.

```
Integrate[1/( Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}]
```

Mathematica is unable to provide an answer directly. Is there another way to obtain an analytical answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Rubi`](https://rulebasedintegration.org/)

```
Get["Rubi`"]

Assuming[f > 0 && b > 0, Int[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}]]
```

> [image: rubi]

Edit: Without Rubi and giving an extra assumption

```
FullSimplify@
 Assuming[f > 0 && b > 0 && a > 1, 
  Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}]]
```

> [image: res2]

Edit 3: Noteworthy

```
FullSimplify@
   Assuming[f > 0 && b > 0, Int[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}]] // 
  TrigToExp // Simplify
```

[image: rubiagain]

Comment: Note to OP: In case you're unfamiliar with Rubi, it's an add-on package developed by Albert Rich.  Installation instructions can be found here:  https://rulebasedintegration.org

Comment: @theorist many thanks. I have added the link to the answer

Answer (score 5):

Expanding the integrand into a series

```
coef[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 0, n}]
```

[image]

Verifying the series expansion,

```
1/Sqrt[f + b*x^2] == Sum[coef[n] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity, 2}] // 
 Simplify[#, f > 0] &

(* True *)
```

Exchanging the order of integration and summation, the integral is

```
int = Assuming[{a > 1, f > 0}, 
  Sum[Integrate[coef[n] x^n, {x, 1, a}], {n, 0, Infinity, 2}]]

(* (-ArcSinh[Sqrt[b/f]] + ArcSinh[a Sqrt[b/f]])/Sqrt[b] *)
```

The [`Rubi result`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266641/9362) provided by bmf is

```
int2 = -ArcTanh[Sqrt[b/(b + f)]]/Sqrt[b] + ArcTanh[a/Sqrt[a^2 + f/b]]/Sqrt[b];
```

Numerically, comparing the results

```
And @@ Table[int == int2 /. {
    a -> RandomReal[{11/10, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 15],
    b -> RandomReal[{1/10, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 15],
    f -> RandomReal[{1/10, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]}, {10000}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Very clever approach!

Answer (score 4):

Extending a trick I picked up from one of Daniel Lichtblau's answers, we can try substituting symbolic mathematical constants for the parameters `f` and `b`, and for the upper integration limit `a`, and then then back-substitute:

```
expr = (1/Sqrt[f + b*x^2]) /. {f -> Khinchin, b -> GoldenRatio};
int = Integrate[expr, {x, 1, Catalan}]
int1 = int /. {Khinchin -> f, GoldenRatio -> b, Catalan -> a}
```

[image]

[image]

Note that since these mathematical constants are all specific real-valued positive numbers, the answer may not be general.  Nevertheless, in this case, it gives an answer identical to Bob Hanlon's, whose only restrictions were $a > 1, f > 0$.

Comment: `Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, GenerateConditions -> False]`  yields this result without tricks, while with assumptions in the questions `Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, Assumptions -> b > 0 && f > 0 && a \[Element] Reals]` it returns that with condition `a>1`.

Comment: @Artes  Ah--I assumed the other posters had already tried those more basic approaches before giving their answers, but I should have checked those myself.

Answer (score 2):

The older version 8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) has no problems with that integral at all.

Let me show, how it works with different assumptions:

```
int1[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> {f > 0, b > 0, a > 1}]

(*   Log[(a b + Sqrt[b (a^2 b + f)])/(b + Sqrt[b (b + f)])]/Sqrt[b]   *)

int2[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> {f > 0, b > 0}]

(*   ConditionalExpression[(-ArcSinh[Sqrt[b/f]] + 
  ArcSinh[a Sqrt[b/f]])/Sqrt[b], a > 1]   *)

int1[a, b, f] == int2[a, b, f] // TrigToExp // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {f > 0, b > 0, a > 1}] &

(*   True   *)

int3[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> {f > 0, b \[Element] Reals}]

(*   ConditionalExpression[-((
  I Log[(a + Sqrt[a^2 + f/b])/(1 + Sqrt[(b + f)/b])])/Sqrt[-b]), 
 b + f < 0 && a > 1]   *)

int4[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[{b, f}, Reals]]

(*   ConditionalExpression[-((
  I Log[(a + Sqrt[a^2 + f/b])/(1 + Sqrt[(b + f)/b])])/Sqrt[-b]), 
 f > 0 && b + f < 0 && a > 1]   *)

int5[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[{b, f}, Reals], a < 1}]

(*   ConditionalExpression[-((
  I Log[(a + Sqrt[a^2 + f/b])/(1 + Sqrt[(b + f)/b])])/Sqrt[-b]), 
 f > 0 && a > 0 && a^2 b + f < 0]   *)

int6[a_, b_, f_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[{b, f}, Reals], a < 0}]

(*   ConditionalExpression[(-ArcSinh[Sqrt[b/f]] + 
  ArcSinh[a Sqrt[b/f]])/Sqrt[b], (b >= 0 || a + Sqrt[-(f/b)] > 0) && 
  f > 0 && b + f > 0]   *)

nint[a_, b_, f_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/(Sqrt[f + b*x^2]), {x, 1, a}, MaxRecursion -> 50]
```

Comparison with numerical integration indicates, that `int1`  is valid for all parameter values. (Didn't check it intensivly)

```
tab = (Table[
       With[{a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-3] &, 
         b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-3] &, 
         f = RandomReal[{-3, 3}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-3] &}, {{a, b, 
          f}, nint[a, b, 
          f], {int1[a, b, f] // N}, {int2[a, b, f] // 
           N}, {int3[a, b, f] // N}, {int4[a, b, f] // 
           N}, {int5[a, b, f] // N}, {int6[a, b, f] // N}}], {10}] /. 
      Undefined -> {}) // Quiet // Chop // MatrixForm
```